# what is the difference between System.getProperty("somestring") vs SystemProperties.get("somestring") in android?

Tags: android

what is the difference between

> System.getProperty("somestring")

vs

> SystemProperties.get("somestring")

in android?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`android.os.SystemProperties` interacts with the Android properties system - some keys have completely static values defined in `/system/build.prop` (such as `ro.build.id`), some represent system settings (such as `persist.sys.timezone`), and some are dynamic (such as `sys.powerctl` which can be written to reboot). These are the same values you can access via `adb shell propget` and `adb shell propset`. This interface is **not** part of the public API.

`java.util.System` is a public Java interface. Java [system properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html) include keys such as `java.io.tmpdir` and `user.home`, which are expected by common Java code. They are not related to Android's system properties.